# Deploying django app to production server, should I include environment (env) in git clone?

Tags: python, django, git

I have a working django app running on mý localhost. It is running inside a virtual environment.

No I want to deploy the same project into a Google Compute Engine.
For that I have a question.

After I set up the production server including starting the virutal environment with `vritualenv env` do I need to clone in the project code from git including the `env` directory or only the source code including manage.py?

The process is described differently and so it is a bit confusing.

Main problem is the clarity of deploying the django app to production and the virtual environment setup using git for the code transfer.

Thank you for flow explanation.

My local structure is the following:

```
valuation     <-- project directory w/ manage.py
   valuation  <-- project w/ settings.py
     prophet  <-- app
```

In my production server I have the following structure

```
opt/valuation    <-- virtual environment
   valuation     <-- empty directory, [this][1] says I should clone code here
```

My question is what should I clone from my local project and what do keep out (mainly the manage.py, settings.py etc) so that the project will run.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no You don't need the clone the env folder, just make the requirements.text file , which will track all the plugins used in that project.You can update the requirements file using command

```
pip freeze > requirements.text
```

on the server just create the new env and install all the plugins using below command

```
pip install -r requirements.text
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused as to how to structure the directories on prod vs my local setup. In my production I have /opt/valuation/ <- the virtualenvironment.
Locally I have valuation/valuation/prophet (as to projectDirectory/project/app). Which goes where in the production server?

Comment: virtural enviroment can be any where, to run project just you have to run from that virtualenv

Comment: It seems that locally I have my app and the virtual environment spearate but in server they are inside of each other. That begs the question of weather I should include the manage.py also in the propduction?

Comment: suppose /opt/apps/
create the virtual environment here
virtualenv env
now clone the project, after cloning there will be one more folder, created
just activate the virtualenv 
source env/bin/activate
go the project folder, 
run ./manage.py runserver

if you want to run in background you can user supervisor